# Django SECRET_KEY : Copying hashed passwords into different Django project

Tags: python, django, security, django-models, django-settings

I have a Django powered site(Project-1) running with some users registered on it. I am now creating a revamped version of the site in a new separate Django project(Project-2) which I would make live once finished. I would need to populate the User data along with their hashed passwords currently in database of Project-1 into database of Project-2. Would having different `SECRET_KEY`s for Project-1 and Project-2 be an issue to get the hashed passwords migrated and working in Project-2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `settings.SECRET_KEY` is not used for password hashing